# android horizontal scrollview working with seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar, horizontalscrollview

In my app I have a horizontal scrollview of 6 duck images, while the horizontal scrollview can work properly, now I would like to add a SeekBar underneath the horizontal scrollview such that moving the seekbar will positioning the horizontal scrollview to the proper item.

## I have written the codes as follows:

### Seekbar:

```
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
        {
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);

            if (progress ==5)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(R.drawable.d_duck400_5, 0);}
            if (progress ==4)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(R.drawable.d_duck400_4, 0);}
            if (progress ==3)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(R.drawable.d_duck400_3, 0);}
            if (progress ==2)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(R.drawable.d_duck400_2, 0);}
            if (progress ==1)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(R.drawable.d_duck400_1, 0);}
            if (progress ==0)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(R.drawable.d_duck400_0, 0);}
        }
    });         
}
```

### Horizontal Scrollview:

```
    private void getDeviceWidth() 
    {  
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);  
        mWidth = dm.widthPixels;  
    }  

    private void initView() 
    {  
        int[] imageArray = { R.drawable.d_duck400_0, R.drawable.d_duck400_1, R.drawable.d_duck400_2, 
                R.drawable.d_duck400_3, R.drawable.d_duck400_4, R.drawable.d_duck400_5};

//        int[] imageArray = { R.drawable.d_duck1_400, R.drawable.d_duck1_400, R.drawable.d_duck1_400, 
//              R.drawable.d_duck1_400, R.drawable.d_duck1_400, R.drawable.d_duck1_400};

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollview_layout);
        mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {// Place 6 items into horizontalscrollview
            int width = mWidth /1;  
            LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(Duck.this, R.layout.d_scrollview_item, null);
            itemLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));// set the width as 1 screen showing 3 items  
            itemLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageview);  
            TextView mTextView = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview);  

            final String page = "The" + (i + 1) + "th page";  

            mTextView.setText(page);  
            mImageView.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[i]);  

            mLinearLayout.addView(itemLayout);  

            itemLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
            {  
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {  
//                    Toast.makeText(Duck.this, "Click" + page, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    return false;  
                }
            });  
        } 
    }
```

## Question:

Once I move the seekbar, the pictures in the horizontal Scrollview all gone.

What is happening? Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (progress ==5)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(R.drawable.d_duck400_5, 0);
```

`scrollTo` expects x,y coordinates to scroll to a new position. But you give it `R.drawable.d_duck400_5` as x value. This will be just a random integer produced by compiler. It is not the x coordinate you want to scroll.

Try something like this:

```
if (progress ==5)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(200, 0);
if (progress ==5)  {mLinearLayout.scrollTo(400, 0);
....
```

If you want to find the position of a view, you can go with `getLocationInWindow` or `getLocationOnScreen` methods.

```
int[] location = new int[2];
yourView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
```

Comment: I would like to ask whether the x in mLinearLayout.scrollTo(x, 0); can accept float? it is because I would like to change a bit as the progress of the seeekbar is continuous rather than integer, and it would be better if the horizontal scrollview can scroll continuously upon changes of the progress of the seekbar

Comment: Being float or integer for x is not related to the scrolling speed. If you want to scroll it slowly, then you should use an animation.